# Cant' access elements margin-left

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

In the following snippet, I seem unable to access the current `margin-left` css property of `.circle`. I created a [PLUNKr](https://plnkr.co/edit/cCxeUOiVqi1cS0SD3iKB?p=preview) which showcases this.

I am trying to access this property as I need to adjust a property binding calculation on mobile which requires the `left-margin`.

This is a breakdown of what I have:

```
<div class="circle"  [ngStyle]="{'width': calcCircleWidth()}"></div>

.circle {
    margin: 40px 20px;
}

private calcCircleWidth(): string {
    var html: HTMLElement = (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.circle:first-child'))
    ...
}
```

This is the result when I log properties of `var html: HTMLElement`

```
html \\ <div class="circle" _ngcontent-iai-1="" style="width: 50%;">
html.style \\ CSS2Properties { width: "50%" } 
html.style.marginLeft \\ (nothing)
```

Comment: Something crazy has happened to my plunkr - fixing it now,.

Comment: Plunkr has been fixed.

Comment: The Plunker is about 2.0.0-beta.0. That's more than a year old. Just use the `new` button in Plunker to get a Plunker template for a recent Angular version.

Comment: Are you sure an element that's not yet added to the DOM is supposed to have dimensions?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  ok I will fix the template, I just went via the google link for ng2 template... oh so you're saying that this function is getting called prior to the element being instantiated in the DOM?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. You can be sure the element is added to the DOM at this point. Margin-left is just `""`, that's all.

Comment: The value is empty, because you are actually checking the style attribute of that element. As your styles are declared in a CSS block, you can use window.getComputedStyle (not sure how in TS).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So it doesn't retain the CSS value?

Comment: @todinov so the style attribute is different to the styles defined in CSS? Interesting.

Comment: What CSS value? You want to get the value back that you assigned using the binding?

Comment: What @todinov said https://plnkr.co/edit/vZ2Thl7UUc0Zlj9xVNpU?p=preview. This is not related to TS or Angular in any way. This is just how the browser and JS work.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer.

Comment: Thank you @todinov you were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code

```
<div class="circle"  [ngStyle]="{'width': calcCircleWidth()}"></div>

.circle {
    margin: 40px 20px;
}
```

Since `margin` is *NOT* a style attribute on the element, you cannot access it from the `style` member of the dom element.

## More

The proper way to get *computed* style that takes the style attribute and CSS into account is to use `getComputedStyle`. Docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle